# Printing a list of keys which satisfy a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, if I am given a dictionary which has integers, mapped with other integers, and if i have to print a list of keys having a value which isn't repeated in the dictionary, how do I do that?
For example the dictionary {1:0, 3:2, 4:2, 5:2}, should give [1].

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> import collections
>>> data = {1:0, 3:2, 4:2, 5:2}
>>> counts = collections.Counter(data.values())
>>> [k for k in data if counts[data[k]] == 1]
[1]
```